# Can gnuplot draw interactive graph items?

Tags: c++, qt, gnuplot

I always assumed gnuplot just produced static jpeg (or whatever) images.  Recently I downloaded and compiled [this package](http://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/) which demonstrated that gnuplot also (at a minimum) is capable of zooming and rotating images.

My question (1) is whether it can also interactively draw lines (sorry if that is not the correct terminology) and such.  For instance, if I have generated a sales or stock graph, is gnuplot capable of using the mouse to draw a trend line or similiar?  (2) If it is capable of this, is it then possible to save the altered graph?  (3) Can gnuplot graphs be easily incorporated into a QT GUI application?

Thanks much for any answers and references or examples.

Comment: small tip: take a look at qwt library at http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot 4.6 includes Qt support.  There is example code in the distribution package that show how to embed the output into a simple Qt application.

Answer (score 0):

It is capable of doing some of the things you described (although it may take some creativity/reliance on external programs, etc...).  See the help for `mouse` and more importantly `bind`, `help mouse variables`, etc.  And finally, embedding in a QT application is probably the most difficult ... (although I am not completely familiar with the QT framework).  I'm not entirely sure that one is possible.

Sorry to get to your question so late, but I though I would answer in case someone else wants to do something similar.